# How to have express handle and capture my errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

```
var database = require('database');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
});


app.post('/dosomething', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {

     if (!req.body.a) {
        res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
            error: 'a not defined'
        }));
        return;
    }


    firstAsyncFunction(req.body.a, function(err, result) {

        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send('firstAsyncFunction was NOT a success!');
        } else {
            if (result.b) {

                secondAsyncFunction(result.b, function(err, data) {

                    if (err) {
                        res.status(500).send('secondAsyncFunction was NOT a success!');
                        return;

                    }
                        res.send('EVERYTHING WAS A SUCCESS! ' + data);

                });

            }
            else {
                res.status(500).send('result.b is not defined');

            }
        }

    }); 

});

function firstAsyncFunction(param, callback) {

        //Some network call:
        // Return either return (callback(null,'success'));  or return (callback('error'));

        var query = database.createQuery(someOptionsHere);
        database.runDatabaseQuery(query, function(err, entities, info) {
        if (err) {
            return (callback('error'));
        }
        return (callback(null, 'success'));
    });

};
function secondAsyncFunction(param, callback) {


        //Some network call:
        // Return either return (callback(null,'success'));  or return (callback('error'));

        var query = database.createQuery(someOptionsHere);
        database.runDatabaseQuery(query, function(err, entities, info) {
        if (err) {
            return (callback('error'));
        }
        return (callback(null, 'success'));
    });

};



var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});


module.exports = app;
```

I have here a basic express http server. This server has one route, dosomething, which makes two network calls and tells the user if they were a success or not.

This is my entire webserver (this is a bare bones server of my actual server for example purposes).  I am now concerned with this server crashing. Reading the docs for express I see there is a default error handler which will catch errors and prevent the server from crashing (http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html). I have added the code:

```
function defaultErrorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  if (res.headersSent) {
    return next(err);
  }
  res.status(500);
  res.render('error', { error: err });
}

app.use(defaultErrorHandler);
```

This still crashes my server though. For example. I had a problem with my database returning an improper JSON response and inside of my firstAsyncFunction (not shown in the code)  I tried to parse the JSON and it caused an error telling me it was improper JSON and the server crashed and was unable to take requests anymore until I restarted it. I would like to avoid this and have the default error handler send out a generic response back to the user when this occurs. I thought if I specified the defaultErrorHandler and put it inside of app.use that it would capture and handle all errors, but this does not seem to be the case? Inside of my async function for example you can see I am looking if an error was returned and if it was I send an error back to the user, but what if some other error occurs, how can I get express to capture and handle this error for me?

Comment: Give this a try [connect-domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080887/centralizing-error-handling-in-an-express-js-based-app?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: I have just read that the domain API is deprecated in nodejs

Answer (score 0):

The `defaultErrorHandler` cannot handle exceptions that are thrown inside asynchronous tasks, such as callbacks.

If you define a route like:

```
app.get('/a', function(req, res) {
    throw new Error('Test');
});
```

An error will be thrown, and in this case `defaultErrorHandler` will successfully catch it.

If the same exception occurs in an async manner, like so:

```
app.get('/a', function(req, res) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        throw new Error('Test');
    }, 1000);
});
```

The server will crush, because the callback is actually in another context, and exceptions thrown by it will now be caught by the original catcher. This is a very difficult issue to deal with when it comes to callback.

There is more than one solution though. A possible solution will be to wrap every function that is prone to throw error with a `try` `catch` statement. This is a bit excessive though.

For example:

```
app.get('/a', function(req, res) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        try {
            var x = JSON.parse('{');
        }
        catch (err) {
            res.send(err.message);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

---

### A nicer solution:

A nicer solution, would be to use promises instead, if it's possible, then for example you can declare a single `errorHandler` function like so:

```
function errorHandler(error, res) {
    res.send(error.message);
}
```

Then, let's say you have to following function with fetches stuff from the database (I used `setTimeout` to simulate async behavior):

```
function getStuffFromDb() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve("{");
        }, 100);
    });
}
```

Notice that this function returns an invalid JSON string. Your route will look something like:

```
app.get('/a', function(req, res) {
    getStuffFromDb()
        .then(handleStuffFromDb)
        .catch(function (error) { errorHandler(error, res) });
});

function handleStuffFromDb(str) {
    return JSON.parse(str);
}
```

This is a very simplified example, but you can add a lot more functionality to it, and (at least theoretically) have a **single catch statement** which will prevent your server from crushing.